# Visual Studio.NET like property window in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Looking for a VS.NET like property window that can be embedded in ASP.NET page, which will allow users to change decorated proerties of a class.

any guidance is much appreciated

thanks

Comment: when there are acceptable solutions, i will .... peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote one ages back. It is hosted on CodePlex. I don't support the project.

http://propertygrid.codeplex.com/